# Factorise the expression

Tags: factoring

Factorise of the expression  $$ a^4+b^4-c^4-2a^2b^2+4abc^2~ \\(S:(a + b - c) (a + b + c) (a^2+ b^2 + c^2 - 2 a b))$$

I tried to solve this problem:
 $$ a^4+b^4-c^4-2a^2b^2+4abc^2\rightarrow\\\
(a^2-b^2)^2-c^4+4abc^2\rightarrow\\\
(a^2-b^2-c^2)(a^2-b^2+c^2)+4abc^2\\\
((a-b)(a+b)-c^2)((a-b)(a+b)+c^2)+4abc^2$$ but I stopped here. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Well, why did you stop? What confused you?

Comment: I don't see the solution!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.You should actually do:
\begin{split}
a^4+b^4-c^4-2a^2b^2+4abc^2 & = (a^4+b^4 + 2a^2b^2) - (4a^2b^2 + c^4 - 4abc^2) \\
& = (a^2+b^2)^2 - (c^2-2ab)^2 \\
& = (a^2+b^2-c^2+2ab)(a^2+b^2+c^2-2ab) \\
& = ((a+b)^2 - c^2) (a^2+b^2+c^2-2ab) \\
& = (a+b+c)(a+b-c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-2ab)
\end{split}

In the first step, I added and subtracted $4a^2b^2$, and in the second step grouped them into squares. From then, it is just the formula $x^2-y^2 = (x+y)(x-y)$ applied twice.

In your attempt, the $4abc^2$ was just left hanging. That shoul have been dealt with by trying to bring it into the expansion of a square term (which I did).

Comment: Nice and elegant (+1).

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan Thank you.

Comment: You added and subtracted $2a^2b^2$ (not $4a^2b^2$).

Comment: I added $4a^2b^2$ to $-2a^2b^2$ to make it $+2a^2b^2$, which came into the first bracket In the first line). In the second bracket on the same line, is the subtracted $-4a^2b^2$. But anyway, I see how you may have observed the addition/subtraction of $2a^2b^2$ instead. It makes no difference, since both retain equality.

Comment: @Adren Actually, he meant that $$-2a^2b^2=-2a^2b^2+[4a^2b^2-4a^2b^2]=2a^2b^2-4a^2b^2.$$

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan Thank you for the additional clarification.

Comment: of course, that's correct. What I meant is : $-2a^2b^2=\{mathbf}{2a^2b^2-2^a^2b^2}-2a^2b^2$.

Comment: @Adren I see. I hope this is a minor point (I think it is, because there seem to be no questions from the questioner about this).

Comment: Thanks a lot астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг!!!  I got the wrong way !!!

Comment: @petaarantes You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

As a quadratic in $c^2\,$, the reduced discriminant of $-(c^4-4ab \cdot c^2-a^4-b^4+2a^2b^2)$ is:

$$
\frac{1}{4}\Delta = 4a^2b^2 +a^4+b^4-2a^2b^2=(a^2+b^2)^2
$$

Therefore the roots are $c^2=2ab \pm (a^2+b^2) = \{(a+b)^2, -(a-b)^2\}\,$ giving the factorization:

$$
\begin{align}
-\left(c^2-(a+b)^2\right)\left(c^2+(a-b)^2\right) & = -(c-a-b)(c+a+b)(c^2+a^2-2ab+b^2) \\[3px]
 & = (a+b-c)(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-2ab)
\end{align}
$$